# Tarski's plank problem using simple methods

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to solve this problem:

> Is it possible to cover a circular well of diameter $1$ meters with 100 meters (or any big $N$) long and $\delta>0$ wide planks, which satisfy: $\sum_{all planks}{\delta}<1$.

**Disclaimer:** I'm trying to solve this problem by simple methods. Meaning: no measure approach and Archimede's expansion into sphere and cylinder.

**My work so far** *(using article by Jonathan L. King):*

Let's define:

1. Every plank as $P_n$ with width $\delta$ and length $N$;
2. The area of plank $P_n$ as: $$S(P_n)=\delta N;$$
3. The area of plank $P_n$ in the well $D$ area as: $$S(P'_n)=S(P_n\cap D);$$

Then this is true:

**Lemma 1**

The biggest area is covered by two planks: $S(P_n\cup P_m)$ when they don't overlap: $S(P_n\cap P_m)=0$.

Now, let's say we succeeded and managed to cover $D$ with: $$C=\bigcup_k{P'_k}.$$ Furthermore, let's say that $C$ is *minimal cover*: no part of **current** $P'_k$ can be moved moved outside $D$ and well be still covered. From $C$ being *minimal* and *Lemma 1* we conclude, that: $$\tag2 \bigcap_k{P'_k}=\emptyset.$$

[image]

For two planks $P$ and $R$, which have a gap between them, two parallel lines $L_1$ and $L_2$ can be drawn in a way that points on the edge of planks: $p_1, r_1\notin L_1, p_2; r_2\notin L_2$. Therefore: $$Length(L_1)=\bigcup_l{Q_l}\cap L_1$$
and due to $L_1$ and $L_2$ being parallel:
$$Length(L_1)\le Length(L_2).$$
This can be done in reverse too ($Length(L_2)\le Length(L_1)$). So:$$Length(L_1)=Length(L_2).$$
**Conclusion 1**

$P$ and $R$ are parallel. Therefore, for *minimal cover* $C$ all planks are in parallel and: $$\sum_{P'_k\in C}\delta=1.$$
**The problem**

[image]

The method I apply skips perpendicular planks. It is obviously measurable that any perpendicular arrangement is much worse than parallel one (therefore not minimal cover). However, I'm not able to prove that it is so.